# How to raise max file limit on Linux CentOS 7

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sonarqube

This question is asked before but it is still not clear how this works to me. SonarQube fails to start with this message

> ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed [1]: max file descriptors [4096]
>   for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]

We can check of course that settings are not correct

```
[root@sonarqube ~]# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
381766
[root@sonarqube ~]# cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
262144
[root@sonarqube ~]# ulimit -Hn
4096
[root@sonarqube ~]# ulimit -Sn
1024
```

The first thing I tried was to add `LimitNOFILE` to my service file. That doesn't work. Anymore, I think it used to work at some point.

```
[Unit]
Description=SonarQube 7.9.1
After=network.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=sonarqube
Group=sonarqube
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/lib/jvm/jdk11_0411_oj9/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube/lib/sonar-application.jar
StandardOutput=syslog
LimitNOFILE=262144
LimitNPROC=8192
TimeoutStartSec=5
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next I added a file `/etc/security/91-nofiles.conf` with

```
 * soft nofile 262144
 * hard nofile 262144
```

And a file `/etc/sysctl.d/sonarqube.conf`

```
fs.file-max=262144
```

These files also don't make a difference. Same error. So the 4096 seems to be fixed somewhere. Is there a way to actually change this value?

Comment: Does adding the two nofile settings to /etc/security/limits.conf maybe work? Don't forget to restart the X session afterwards (i.e. logout, login).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do these changes :

```
# /etc/pam.d/common-session and add this line
session required pam_limits.so
# /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive and add this line
session required pam_limits.so
```